# Where is state stored in fluxor?

Tags: c#, blazor, flux, state-management, fluxor

I am new to working with state management. Currently I am working on a blazor application and I stumbled across the "fluxor" framework which allows state management via the flux pattern.
Fluxor is working perfectly for me, however I can't seem to figure out where the State of a page is actually stored.
Is it in cache, a db or some other fancy way? Is there a way for me to see that stored data in the browser?

I use fluxor on the client side of my application by the way.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: If @Eric King is around he can answer this one - there's a set of articles he's written at https://dev.to/mr_eking/advanced-blazor-state-management-using-fluxor-part-1-696

Answer (score 6):

State is kept in memory. You can view the state with a nice GUI by enabling Redux Devtools with `.UseReduxDevTools()` like this:

```cs
services.AddFluxor(o => o
    .ScanAssemblies(typeof(SomeType).Assembly)
    .UseReduxDevTools());
```

Then use the redux devtools addin:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en

[image]

If you wish to save the state to localstorage or a database I made a library to persist the state called Fluxor.Persist:

https://github.com/Tailslide/fluxor-persist

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I have seen the ReduxDevTools before, however they don't seem to work for me. Whenever I add the .UseReduxDevTools() to the standard counter state example, the counter won't count up anymore. 

Do you have an idea what the problem there could be? 
Or is there a way that I can look at the state without the ReduxDevTools? Something built in the browser?

Comment: @Snoopy111 The counter stops changing when you include .UseReduxDevTools on the Fluxor counter sample? If so, could you file a bug report on the Fluxor repo please?

Comment: @Snoopy111 you could run the sample project from fluxor persist and have it persist to localstorage then you can hit F12 in the browser and see your state in localstorage.  I think it's better to figure out why .UseReduxDevTools() isn't working for you though it's perfect for this.

Answer (score 2):

An `IStore` is instantiated as a Scoped dependency. Ultimately this is the root of everything for the current user.

When you inject `IStore`, `IState<Whatever>` `IDispatcher`, `IActionSubscriber` they will ultimately come from the state that is stored within that `IStore` instance.

If you inject IStore into something you can iterate through its Features property, which is a dictionary of `IFeature` keyed by name (the name being from `IFeature.GetName`).

The IFeature has an `object GetState()` method you can use to grab the state.

This is the non-generic way of accessing the state. The state is actually stored using generics.

Look at the ReduxDevTools code and you will see an example of how to get all state (to send to ReduxDevTools browser plugin) using `IStore.Features` and `GetState`

https://github.com/mrpmorris/Fluxor/blob/master/Source/Fluxor.Blazor.Web.ReduxDevTools/ReduxDevToolsMiddleware.cs#L67

and in the `OnJumpToState` method it shows how I restore historical states from the browser plugin

https://github.com/mrpmorris/Fluxor/blob/master/Source/Fluxor.Blazor.Web.ReduxDevTools/ReduxDevToolsMiddleware.cs#L92