# State is wiped out when page is refresh in blazor with fluxor

Tags: c#, blazor, state-management, fluxor

I am not sure how to handle this behavior, this is the Feature I have:

```js
public class HolderFeature : Feature<HolderState>
    {
        public override string GetName() => "HolderState";
        protected override HolderState GetInitialState() => new(holder: new ProductHolder(), persons: string.Empty);        
    }
```

And, everything works fine until a page is refreshed (pressing f5), the state is wiped out, I have this to handle the error:

```js
 protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            if (HolderState.Value.QuotedProduct.Quotes != null)
            {
                //do the logic
            }
            else
            {
              //show error screen
                PressedF5 = true;
            }
        }
```

What I expect is that even when the page is refreshed it shouldn't wipe out the state. how can I do that?

Comment: What is the question?  What is the problem?  It's expected for the state to be wiped out when you refresh -- is that your point?

Comment: @KirkWoll you are right! I edited the post hope this time it is understandable.

Comment: To persist state upon a refresh, you need to store the state somewhere -- either a server-backed database, or browser local storage.  That's a topic too big for an SO question, but [this tutorial](https://dev.to/mr_eking/advanced-blazor-state-management-using-fluxor-part-6-l04) seems to be what you're after.

Comment: I imagined something with local storage or indexdb would be the answer! Thank you if you post your previous post I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: A related question with a library to persist Fluxor data to DB or localStorage on F5.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67421834/943435

Answer (score 1):

The state is stored in memory. When you refresh the page you are unloading it and starting from scratch, so all the memory is lost if it isn't persisted somewhere.